# How to pass function pointers from class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to pass some 3rd party code a list of functions that accept a single parameter, e.g. list.

`run_funcs([m1, m2])`

My code (methods) are part of a class, therefore they take another `self` parameter.

```py
class MyClass():
  def m1(self, o):
    return <something>
  def m2(self, o):
    return <something>
```

Can I somehow extract from an object instance a list of functions runnable by `run_funcs`?
I need to have the methods in the class because I need some initialization (build some lists) which the methods access.

I (think) I should be able to create a list of function from an instance (which will then have the self), but I am not sure how ...

Comment: **Python does not have pointers**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to inspect a class and print a name and
and function reference to each method which has an argspec
of two args see the code block below.

When inspecting the methods' argspec, if it has two args,
the first one in a class method is 'self', thus when calling,
it would only require one arg.

In the loop below: method[0] is the name and 
method[1] is a method reference.

I haven't actually tried it but if you need to generate functions
from a class at runtime, I think this is down the correct path 
to victory.

```
import inspect

class MyClass():
    def m1(self, o):
        return 'method1'
    def m2(self, o):
        return 'method2'

mc = MyClass()

for method in inspect.getmembers(mc): 
    if isinstance(method[1], type(mc.m1)): 
        if len(inspect.getfullargspec(method[1]).args) == 2: 
            print(f'mc.{method[0]}') 
            print(f'  mc.{method[1]}') 

>>> mc.m1
>>>  mc.<bound method MyClass.m1 of <funcs_from_class.MyClass object at 0x11181e6d8>>
>>>mc.m2
>>>  mc.<bound method MyClass.m2 of <funcs_from_class.MyClass object at 0x11181e6d8>>
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting the "bounded method" pointers is what I needed -- now I also know how they're called :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an instance of the class, you can access the methods on the instance:

```
mc = MyClass()
run_funcs([mc.m1, mc.m2])
```